# Automatically turn content in cell into mailto: hyperlink

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, mailto

I am setting up a workflow and would desire when a user pastes or types an email into any cell within a column it is automatically converted to a mailto: hyperlink.

Currently, I have the "email" column of cells with data validation set to "is valid email". Then I have the column of cells to the right of that with the code below. Once working this automation column will be hidden so it just works in the background.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())), "", HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("mailto:",ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))))
```

The results I get is:
 The email cell validates and only allows valid emails but is not converted to hyperlink. The code cell returns the following: mailto:$N$1

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISEMAIL(A1:A), HYPERLINK("mailto:"&A1:A, A1:A), ))
```

[image: 0]